# Apply discount on array of object in loop whichever object paid value is higher?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I have array of object which have key **paid**. I want to apply discount on all objects expect object which paid value is higher using loop.

```
var booking = [
{id:1,paid:200,currency:'USD'},
{id:2,paid:99,currency:'USD'},
{id:3,paid:100,currency:'USD'},
]
```

On above array of object name `booking` i want to make loop and apply discount by adding key `discount:true` in that object except higher `paid` value object.

***This is what i want after loop***

```
var booking = [
{id:1,paid:200,currency:'USD'},
{id:2,paid:99,currency:'USD',discount:true},
{id:3,paid:100,currency:'USD',discount:true},
]
```

Comment: is the data ordered (largest first)? what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz no it is not ordered. I don't have any solution to tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get max `paid` value first and then apply the new property, if necessary.

```js
const
    booking = [{ id: 1, paid: 200, currency: 'USD' }, { id: 2, paid: 99, currency: 'USD' }, { id: 3, paid: 100, currency: 'USD' }],
    max = Math.max(...booking.map(({ paid }) => paid)),
    result = booking.map(o => ({ ...o, ...o.paid === max || { discount: true } }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```